# I need to extend the Session Expiry Timeout/ Login Expiry Timeout in ASP.NET Core Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor Server ASP.net core app. It has Cookie based authentication using RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider. When I login I find '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application' Cookie in my browser.

The problem I am facing is that I want to expend Session Expiry Timeout/Login Expiry Timeout and I am unable to do so.

**Right Now Situation:** After 30 min of my login when I refresh the page it redirects to the login screen which shows that the session has been expired.
**What I want:** I want that either the session does not expire or expires after a really long time.

Help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure cookie expiration settings in startup:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
{
    ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Comment: There is a missing open bracket { before assignments.  Edit wouldn't allow me to change 1 character - states it must be a least 6 BUMMER.

Comment: @JClarkCDS thanks for the notice, just added the missing `{`

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Startup.cs file, add the following code to the ConfigureServices method:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Bearer";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "<your audience>";
            options.Authority = "<your authority>";
        })
```

Replace  and  with the values for your application.

2. Set the JwtBearerOptions in the AddJwtBearer method to include the TokenValidationParameters:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Bearer";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Audience = "<your audience>";
        options.Authority = "<your authority>";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = "<your issuer>",
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "<your audience>"
        };
    })
```

Replace  and  with the values for your application.

3. Finally, set the session timeout in the Configure method:

```
    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await context.ChallengeAsync("oidc");
        }
    });
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/login");
        }
    });
    app.UseSession(); // Add this line
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var userSession = context.Session.GetString("UserSession");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSession))
        {
            context.Session.SetString("UserSession", userSession);
            context.Session.SetInt32("UserSession_Expiry", Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));
        }
        await next();
    });
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
```

In the above code, we set the session timeout to 30 minutes. You can adjust the timeout duration by modifying the AddMinutes method.

Note: Setting the session timeout in this way means that the session timeout will be set for all users of the application. If you need to set different timeouts for different users, you may need to use a different approach.