# Logs out of account for no reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am developing a web application, however, I got a problem. Sometime after authorization, logs out of the account for no reason. I do not understand what the problem is. What could be the problem?

ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(config =>
    {
        config.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    });

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
    {
        config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        config.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
    {
        config.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Login action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Неверный логин или пароль.");

        return View(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66798389/5519026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Session Timeout.

The default session timeout at the Server is 20 minutes but it is configurable. Microsoft. AspNetCore. Session package provides middleware to manage the sessions in ASP.NET Core.

See this for a more detailed view.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0